# How to reproduce the "add as a link" feature on DNX projects?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, dnx

I have a project with some files (xml) with some configuration I would like to share with my integration test project.

Using a regular project I can "Add as a link" the files for that, so when I change the config file the test project is updated as well.

How can I do the same with dnx projects (altering project.json)?

Comment: Have you seen this: https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/147 ?

Comment: @DavidTansey using content? How can I specify the directory they go?